# Limitless String in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

This is a question that has been bugging me for a while and I am no longer working in this so sorry for the lack of code. The situation is this I had a web service that in the client and the server page it had compression and it had encryption. It didn't work all the time because there was accents and that crashed the encryption but when you set it to UTF8 it got fixed. Still there was a set of data that was very BIG and it exceeded the limit of normal string 33 thousand or something characters.

This step happened in the packing and unpacking steps of web services. What was being returned is a Dataset(that in webservices it converts to an XML).

I know StringBuilder can be helpful but I assume that when you change it toString() it will trim the string to the max limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The max limit of a string in .net is *way* beyond 33 thousand or something characters. I guess that what you experienced was that you hit the max limit of a http request (even though that defaults to 4MB, I think). This can be configured in the [`httpRuntime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) element of the web.config file to accomodate larger requests.